# Query Permission Sets for "Manage Flow" new summer 23 release item

Tags: salesforce, reporting, soql, salesforce-flow

Is it possible to run a query to see which permission sets the Manage Flows = True?  With the new summer 23 release there is an option to be more pragmatic with the Flow Permissions in Permission Sets & Profiles (Create/Update) etc..We just want to review our org to ensure no permissions has this already. Its an App Permission now.

I tried the following query. I am unable to locate the new field values to query this for my exising permission sets.

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM PermissionSet
WHERE PermissionsManageFlow = true

INVALID_FIELD: 
WHERE PermissionsManageFlow = true
      ^
ERROR at Row:3:Column:7
No such column 'PermissionsManageFlow' on entity 'PermissionSet'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the correct API name of permission from `title` tag when you hover over the checkbox. Or use workbench/REST API/whatever to run an object "describe" and compare label to api name.

[image]

`/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/PermissionSet/describe` and search JSON for "manage flow"

```
SELECT Id, Name, Profile.Name, IsOwnedByProfile
FROM PermissionSet 
WHERE PermissionsManageInteraction = true
```